# Creating User-PageView Matrix from CSV Table

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, machine-learning

I have a scenario where I need to create a User vs Page View matrix of our web application.

The data is in the form:

```
Page Name       UserName      Count of Page Views by The User
Home            David           12
Home            Minerva         56
Home            Michael         1112
Buy             David           2
Buy             Mike            12
```

I want to create a User vs Page View matrix where each entry in the matrix is the Count.

I am using the Python stack and is there any way I can create the matrix (numpy) automatically?

I guess case by case parsing will be very tedious and this is a general use case, so there must be some function but I couldn't find it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) or [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='Page Name',columns='UserName',values='Count of Page Views by The User')
```

---

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Page Name','UserName'])['Count of Page Views by The User'].unstack()
```

```
print (df1)
UserName   David  Michael  Mike  Minerva
Page Name                               
Buy          2.0      NaN  12.0      NaN
Home        12.0   1112.0   NaN     56.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot @jezrael !! Got the df now. Will start the ml pipeline with numpy :)